# Redirect to a mvc view from custom authorize filter of web api

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am working on an application which has web api in it and my APIs have a custom authorize filter which performs some function on each action and I am trying to redirect to a MVC view within my application by overriding `HandleUnauthorizedRequest` using below code, **Is it possible to do it from Web API's custom authorize filter**

```
 protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(HttpActionContext httpContext)
        {
            var response =  new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);

            string message =
                 "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title> Page Not Found </title></head><body><h2 style='text-align:center'> Sorry, Page Not Found </h2></body></html>";
            response.Content = new StringContent(message);
            response.Content.Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/html");

            httpContext.Response = response;
        }
```

Comment: When you say "has web api in it" do you mean it is a web api project or is it a regular mvc project and you are using certain endpoints as api endpoints?

Comment: it is a regular mvc project which uses some endpoints from apicontrollers

Comment: Yes, it is possible to use the custom authorization filter for your endpoints.  Basically, you want to detect which controller you are coming from and go from there.

Comment: The above code is a part of custom authorize filter for the endpoint but it doesnt render html on the web page as it is a custom filter for apicontrollers

Comment: A response from an api endpoint should include a response code and the response, typically JSON.  If you want to return html (which is very very odd for an api endpoint) then redirect to a different page/action, like `/home/unauthorized`.  Don't try to build the html in the filter, let your controller actions handle that.